# How to manipulate list

Tags: python, string, list

I don't know if my title is correct or it makes sense but that's the only thing that I think of since the split() method turns/splits string inputs into list.

This is my code

```
import re

fruits = "apple,orange,mango*banana"
listOfFruits = re.split("[,*]",fruits)

storage = ""
for i in range(0, len(listOfFruits)):
    storage = storage + ("({}) \n({})\n".format(listOfFruits[i], listOfFruits[i]))
    finalStorage = storage + "\n"
print(finalStorage)
```

And the output looks like this

```
(apple) 
(apple)
(orange) 
(orange)
(mango) 
(mango)
(banana) 
(banana)
```

What I want is that whenever the code sees an asterisk(*), it will automatically indent itself inside of what words was before it

What I would like my output

```
(apple) 
(apple)
(orange) 
(orange)
(mango) 
      (banana) 
      (banana)
(mango)
```

Other example

```
fruits = "mango+banana+grapes,orange+apple
```

The expected output should look like this

```
(mango)
      (banana)
             (grapes)
             (grapes)
      (banana)
(mango)
(orange)
       (apple)
       (apple)
(orange)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would split on `,` and then when iterating over the results, treat any item with `*` differently by using an `if` statement.

If the item has a `*`, split on the `*` and enumerate the results, multiplying the enumerator by `\t` to get the spacing right, then add the reverse of that to the end and join into a single string.

```
fruits = "mango*banana*grapes,orange*apple"
ListOfFruits = fruits.split(',')

storage = ""
for f in ListOfFruits:
    if '*' not in f:
        storage+= ("({}) \n({})\n".format(f,f))
    else:
        tab_fruits = f.split('*')
        p = ['\t'*i + '('+x+')' +'\n' for i,x in enumerate(tab_fruits)]
        p.extend(reversed(p))
        storage+=''.join(p)
    finalStorage = storage + "\n"
print(finalStorage)
```

Ouput

```
(mango)
    (banana)
        (grapes)
        (grapes)
    (banana)
(mango)
(orange)
    (apple)
    (apple)
(orange)
```

Comment: Hello can you please explain what this do, (Sorry new to python) ` p = ['\t'*i + '('+x+')' +'\n' for i,x in enumerate(tab_fruits)]`

Comment: enumerate returns a counter along with each element of the list so we can use `i` the counter, to multiply by the tab - one additional tab for each fruit `x` in the list.  Being encapsulated in the `[ ]` puts all of the results a list

Answer (score 1):

You could use a recursive method to do the hard work, something like this:

```py
def get_levels(section, tab_num=0):
    if not section:
        return ''

    sublevels = get_levels(section[1:], tab_num + 1)

    return '\t'*tab_num + '(' + section[0] + ')\n' + \
                 sublevels + ( '\n' if sublevels else '') + \
           '\t'*tab_num + '(' + section[0] + ')'


def print_fruits(fruits):
    listOfFruits = fruits.split(',')

    storage = ""
    for fruit in listOfFruits:
        storage += get_levels(fruit.split('*'), 0) + '\n'

    print(storage)
```

After calling `print_fruits` with your sample the output is the following:

```
>>> print_fruits("apple,orange,mango*banana")
>>> print_fruits("mango*banana*grapes,orange*apple")
```

```
(apple)
(apple)
(orange)
(orange)
(mango)
        (banana)
        (banana)
(mango)

(mango)
        (banana)
                (grapes)
                (grapes)
        (banana)
(mango)
(orange)
        (apple)
        (apple)
(orange)
```